# Error occurring in twitter API?

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, ios7

When i tried this URL[enter link description here](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/statuses.json) https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/statuses.json in browser shows an error as fallow

{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}

to rectify that issue used https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
this URL this shows an Error as fallows

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

I had logged in twitter also.

I try to use the above two URL but not receiving any data.
**What URL should i Use in IOS to work properly?**

I had tried and i had the added some sample code given in this link [What goes wrong to access twitter timeline account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621056/what-goes-wrong-to-access-twitter-timeline-account/21621220#21621220)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SLRequest - Twitter returns code 215 (Bad authentication data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081530/slrequest-twitter-returns-code-215-bad-authentication-data)

Comment: it returns   code = 34;
  message = "Sorry, that page does not exist"; Can you please help me how to rectify that error ?

Comment: there is code in the answer and user has it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we try the https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json has not used in twitter right now.So that we can use v1.1.In v1.1 we cannot test in browser directly because of https. we need to test proper https packet to test so that we can only implement in programming or some other https tools.